# Shell script to check if the files are available in the file list in a specific directory

Tags: shell, unix

I have a master file by name the `master.txt`. This master file has list of file names:

```
CUSTOMER.dat  
EMPLOYEE.dat  
FINANCE.dat  
SALES.dat  
Fact.dat
```

I need a shell script to check if all the filenames mentioned in the master file (`master.txt`) are available in a particular directory and also check if they are not 0 byte files.

Finally the shell script should display the below details:

- Total no of files available:
- No of non zero byte files available:
- No of zero byte files available:
- No of files missing:
- Missing file names:

Need experts to help me out here please.

Comment: Show us please your code. Or did you not started to code?

Comment: @patrick85 Not yet

Comment: If you not have started what are your problems? You can find out in google how to read a file in bash, stat for files, etc. I can't code your hole idea for you

Comment: One example for reading an file is: #/bin/bash

FILEINPUT=$(cat blah.txt)
echo $FILEINPUT

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                    
ip=master.txt                                                                                                                                                  
for i in `cat "$ip"`                                                                                                                                           
do                                                                                                                                                             
if [ -r $i ];                                                                                                                                                  
  then echo "file $i exists"                                                                                                                                   
else                                                                                                                                                           
    echo "file $i doesnot exist"                                                                                                                               
fi                                                                                                                                                             
done
```